# Modify catalog based on parameter is URL

Tags: magento-1.7

When user is on **products list page** and there is `?sale=1` parameter to URL, I want Magento to display only products that are on sale.

I already found how to filter collection, so it contains only items on sale - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292208/or-and-and-statement-addattributetofilter-magento

I'm trying to modify the collection in `catalog_block_product_list_collection` event, but no matter what changes I apply to it - old products are displayed in catalog.

```
<catalog_block_product_list_collection>
    <observers>
        <my_custom_observer>
            <class>Some_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>catalog_block_product_list_collection</method>
        </my_custom_observer>
    </observers>
</catalog_block_product_list_collection>
```

-

```
public function catalog_block_product_list_collection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();

        if( isset($params['sale']) && (int)$params['sale'] === 1  ) {

            // this part works and test text prints at the beginning of catalog
            echo "test text";


            $collection = $observer->getCollection();
            // this part doesn't work - old collection is displayed in catalog
            $collection->getSelect()->limit(5); // even simple limit doesn't work

        }

}
```

Should I be using some other event? Please recommend what's the best way to modify product collection output for catalog pages.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Started digging in Magento code to find out why the collection isn't modified and found that the problem is caused by default Magento Review observer that uses same event, added in `app/code/core/Mage/Review/etc/config.xml`:

```
        <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
            <observers>
                <review>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>review/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml</method>
                </review>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
```

And the function which it refers to:

```
 public function catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    if ($productCollection instanceof Varien_Data_Collection) {

        $productCollection->load();
        Mage::getModel('review/review')->appendSummary($productCollection);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

If I comment line `$productCollection->load();` - everything starts working correctly and my initial filter works. Anyone has any idea how to fix this without editing core file?

Comment: What do you mean by old products? What do you want to show?

Comment: Edited, please check again. By "old products" I mean default order of catalog.

Comment: Good catch! Edited my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a filter to your collection. And the event is great, best choice.

```
if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('sale')) {
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    $collection->setPageSize(5);
}
```

Good catch this observer.

To define the "order" of the observer (which shouldn't be relied on) you can just add a `<depends>` in your `Module.xml` in `app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml`:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Eav>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core/>
            </depends>
        </Mage_Eav>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And what you want your Module to depend on is `Mage_Review`

Comment: Ty. But not sure if I understand how adding `addAttributeToFilter('sale', 1)` will help. For example, how do I limit the product collection so it contains only 5 products?

Comment: I read nothing about limit the collection :-) updated.

Comment: I don't have "sale" attribute on products. I just want to filter to product list (e.g. by limiting it to 5 products)  when I have "sale=1" in my URL.

Comment: ah ok, then just remove the addAttributeToFilter

Comment: That's the problem. When I use this code - nothing changes in product collection - old products are displayed, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Because you have no filter and nothing on your collection, it just limits the collection to five products. The content is still the same, products from your category(if any) or from your store

Comment: Shouldn't it display 5 products on first product page when I call `setPageSize(5)`? Because currently it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, we stop this here. Please edit the question and describe what you want to achieve and where.

Comment: Edited, please refer to second block of code. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your own `app/etc/modules/NAMESPACE_MODULE.xml`:

```
<Mage_Review>
    <depends>
        <Timonline_CatalogSorting />
    </depends>
</Mage_Review>
```

So in my case it becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Timonline_CatalogSorting>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Timonline_CatalogSorting>
        <Mage_Review>
            <depends>
                <Timonline_CatalogSorting />
            </depends>
        </Mage_Review>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This forces the order of the events hooking into `catalog_block_product_list_collection`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order in which the observers are executed, as you noticed.

You can that with dependencies (as also described here: [Magento Observer Events - order of operations](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/373/magento-observer-events-order-of-operations/409)), but adding a dependency from a core module to yours seems hacky and might cause other problems.

In your case, you have another possibility. Observers, registered in `<global>` are executed before the area specific observers in `<frontend>` and `<adminhtml>`. Fortunately the observer from `Mage_Review` has been registered in the `frontend` area. As soon as you register yours globally, it will be executed first, thus before the collection is loaded:

```
<global>

    <events>

        <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
            <observers>
                <my_custom_observer>
                    <class>Some_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>catalog_block_product_list_collection</method>
                </my_custom_observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_list_collection>

    </events>

</global>
```

The event is not used anywhere in the admin panel, so there are no other side effects to expect.