# Does it make any difference whether I declare my <observers> inside <global>, <frontend> , <default>, <admin>, <adminthtml>?

Tags: magento-1, event-observer

At the surface, all seem to work.
Are there any less obvious implications/consequences of choosing one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento has three "areas" by default: `frontend`, `adminhtml` and `install`, which are used to separate several things like translations and designs.

The area is loaded and set once when Magento is initialized, see `Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::load()` for details. You will notice an additional area `admin`, but it seems like this is not used (anywhere anymore?). Some modules might add new areas, for example `test` by `EcomDev_PHPUnit`.

Observers are also defined per area, but additionally you can define then in `<global>` so that they apply in all areas.

**Only observers defined in the *current area* and in `global` will be executed. Global observers always come first.**

Defining an observer in `<default>` or `<admin>` actually should *not* work at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You wrote "install" area. Did you mean "global" area (Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL) ?

Comment: No, I meant `install` - it is used during the Magento installation wizard. Take a look at `Mage_Install_Controller_Action` (actually this one seems to be only used for the theme, so you cannot create observers specifically for `install`)

Answer (score 11):

If you call observer between `<frontend></frontend>` then that observer event will only be executed on the frontend.if you write between `<adminhtml></adminhtml>` it will only be executed in the backend and if you write between `<global></global>` then the observer event will work on both frontend and backend.

for example take one event called "core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after"

Case 1:-

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
      <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
      </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Observer event `"<core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>"`  will only work in the backend

Case 2:-

```
<frontend>
    <events>
      <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
      </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Observer event `"<core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>"`  will only work in the frontend

Case 3:-

```
<global>
    <events>
      <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
      </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Observer event `"<core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>"`  will only work in the frontend and backend