# My three modules use same observer use but my third module should run same observer in last

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, dependency

How  to set order of same observer in my three modules?

My each three modules declares same observer.

**My first** `test1_module1` module use `sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item` observer

**My second** `test1_module2` module use same`sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item` observer so I added `<depends><Test1_Module1/></depends>` this code in  `app/etc/modules/Test1_Module2.xml`  and I extends `Test1_Module1_Model_Observer` class in second module observer file

**My third** `test1_module3` module use `sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item` observer.

And My second module `test1_module2` is optional so it may be present or not in `test1` package 
 **My last third module should run same observer in last(after first and second module) what I do ?**

Note: My third module `test1_module3` will dependent on first module `test1_module1` and if second module not present third module same observer should run after first module and if second module present then third module observer should run after first and second module observer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the module loading order which defines the order of observer execution, have a look at: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/74862/243

You have the special case that your third module should be loaded after the second one, but work without it, so you can not depend on it.

The following workaround should do the trick: Write the module definition file for the **second module** like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test1_Module2>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Test1_Module2>
        <Test1_Module3>
            <depends>
                <Test1_Module2 />
            </depends>
        </Test1_Module3>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Since all XML files in `app/etc/modules` are merged before they are evaluated, this will add the dependency from module 3 to module 2, but only if module 2 is installed. If module 2 is installed, but module 3 not, it should not be a problem because the XML above itself does not activate module 3.

---

**Simple and stupid alternative:** Name the modules in alphabetical order.

Comment: It does not require depends code in XML file bcoz if module2 not present and installed module3 in test1 package  it throws error so solution is magento already execute alphabetically order.

Comment: read carefully: the depends declaration goes into the XML file of module2

Comment: Oh sry.it my mistake.your code in module2 XML. Yes exactly what I want. It solved thanks @fschmengler