# CSS file is loaded too early

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, css

I am loading a CSS file via the `local.xml` this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <layout>
        <default>
            <reference name="head">
                <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/style.css</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/style.css</name></action>
            </reference>
        </default>
    </layout>
```

Only problem is that this file is loaded almost at the beginning of the head. How do I get this file, to be loaded at the end of the header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A colleague of mine has found a better solution, so I will post it here:

It seems that Magento 1.9 loads CSS files only last, when they contain an if statement. Instead of the code I used in the `local.xml` file, he replaced it with this:

```
   <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/style.css</name>
        <params/>
        <if><![CDATA[<!--[]><!-->]]></if>
    </action>
```

Comment: That's a neat trick, good to know!

Comment: Works like a charm!  The file gets added right down the bottom of the `<HEAD>` when the above code is included in a `<reference name="head">` block.  Totally eliminates the need for store specific includes in local.xml.

Answer (score 5):

The `default` layout handle is applied before any page specific layout handles, so although `local.xml` updates **within a handle** are applied after all others, the order of operations for building the layout is as follows:

1. `<default>` handle from modules, in [module loading order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/74862/243)
2. `<default>` handle from `theme.xml`
3. `<default>` handle from `local.xml`
4. specific handles from modules, in [module loading order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/74862/243)
5. specific handles from `theme.xml`
6. specific handles handle from `local.xml`

So you have to add your CSS after all layout XML updates are processed and this is possible with an observer for the `controller_action_layout_load_before` event. The observer will look like this:

```
public function addCssAtTheEnd(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{  
    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
    $head = $layout->getBlock('head');
    $head->removeItem('skin_css', 'css/style.css');
    $head->addItem('skin_css', 'css/style.css');
}
```